# How can i predict (linear regression) if there is a response rate bias between calls made in one group to calls made in another group?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear

I am able to do a linear regression model in either python(using scikitlearn) or R (glm) but not sure what my approach would be to do this prediction.

I want to know if there is a response rate bias with customers to be able to estimate a compliance level (how compliant the customers are at taking calls (successfully)) when looking at general call data for compulsory calls against special interview calls, and see if there is a relationship.

I have two data sets on each of these: compulsory calls dataset has millions of attributes and special interview calls dataset has around 5 thousand (and these customers are also in compulsory call data set) but i want to ultimately predict from the successful calls made in compulsory calls what the prediction is for successful special interview calls i.e. are people equally compliant, is there a response rate bias.

But im not sure what features to use from my dataset to do this.
I have:

- number of calls made to each person (int) on compulsory call dataset
- boolean of whether the call was successful/unsuccessful (bool) on compulsory call dataset
- number of calls made to each person (int) on special interview call dataset
- boolean of whether the call was successful/unsuccessful (bool) on special interview call dataset

Or what would i have to do to be able to predict this?

I wanted to see what the outcome is with the odd ratio and the significance of the relationship.

I also have other demographic data (location, sex, age etc) that I would like to try add to this once I have been successful at getting this far.

I saw something like this (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6502/using-simple-linear-regression-to-make-predictions/) but its not exactly what I'm looking for and I'm struggling to piece the logic together, sorry I'm new to this.

If I need to update or edit this post for better clarification please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your desired outcome variable is in this scenario. Depending on that outcome, you have different modeling options. For example, if you want to predict the probability that someone answers any given call, then you have a logistic regression. If you want to predict the number of answered calls out of the total number of calls given to each person, then you have a binomial regression. If you want to predict the number of calls needed to make before a successful answer, then you have a Poisson/negative binomial regression. If you just want to predict the call response rate, then you might consider a gamma regression. I believe that all of those possibilities should be available to you depending on how you combine your data to compute the outcome variable.

My preference in this case would be a multilevel logistic regression (using `glmer` in R), but that might be different from what you want. I would merge the two files together and add a dichotomous indicator variable (0/1) to reflect whether the row belonged originally to the compulsory dataset vs interview dataset. Since the same person is being measured more than once (i.e., being called multiple times), you need a multilevel structure to account for the dependency in the data. In the simplest case, this would mean giving each person a unique intercept for responding to a call (i.e., some people may just be more likely to answer any call while others may be more reluctant to answer). To test your question of whether there's a response bias, then you would add as a predictor the dichotomous indicator. This variable would say whether or not the probability of answering the call is significantly associated with whether the call is compulsory or an interview. The coefficients for a logistic regression are interpretable as odds ratios, which seems to be something you're interested in.

As I said, this is the method I would take because I have a personal bias toward wanting to know what the probability of success would be on any given call. You could easily expand the coefficients to include predictors for the number of previous calls made to the same person, the number of calls previously answered by the person, demographic factors, etc. Plus, within the multilevel model framework, you'd be able to add those predictors as random effects (potentially). While a totally reasonable approach to analyzing the data you have, it might not be practically useful for your specific data question and situation. Similar logic, however, applies to the other kinds of generalized linear regressions.